# iphone safari can't download error on form submit

Tags: php, forms, ios5, download

I'm working on a project. Everything went fine. But on iphone whenever I need to send form data to a script safari shows Download Error and doesn't go to the script.

form is like:

```
<form id="xxx" action="xx" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and the script is like:

```
<?php
if($_POST ['id'])
{
   addToCart ($_POST ['id']);
   redirect ('cart');
}
```

there is nothing else in the form or script. But in iPhone 4s safari show Download error on form submit

anyone faced this before? is it iPhone bug or my script? or any way to fix this (cause I've seen other sites are sending form data without problem on iPhone) ?

Comment: I've checked it on PC, Mac on multiple browser. Android on Multiple browser on 2.3, 2.2, 4. This problem is on iPhone while using 3g network. Using wifi on iPhone didn't show the error.

Comment: It's because we want to redirect the user to cart page. If we omit this redirect the problem doesn't solve. We tested it :(

Comment: No, `redirect()` isn't a native PHP function. What does `redirect()` do exactly ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga I put redirect to make you understand that here goes redirect code, and addToCart for adding to cart code.

Comment: But you said `there is nothing else in the form or script` or is it ?

Comment: ok ok, skip the addToCart and redirect. treat as simple PHP functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, actually the session was creating problem. Cause cookie was creating this issue over AT&T network on iOS due to automatic disconnect. Putting the session in Database solved this issue.